# NameError: name 'now' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

From this source code:

```
def numVowels(string):
    string = string.lower()
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] == "a" or string[i] == "e" or string[i] == "i" or \
            string[i] == "o" or string[i] == "u":
            count += 1
    return count

print ("Enter a statement: ")
strng = input()
print ("The number of vowels is: " + str(numVowels(strng)) + ".")
```

I am getting the following error when I run it:

```
Enter a statement:
now

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stevengfowler\exercise.py", line 11, in <module>
    strng = input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'now' is not defined

==================================================
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(strong)):` not sure if you copy/pasted incorrectly or something, but i`m pretty sure you meant len(string) instead

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

In Python 2, the latter tries to [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) the input, which is what's causing the exception.

In Python 3, there is no `raw_input()`; `input()` would work just fine (it doesn't `eval()`).

Comment: Thank you!  Why did it work in the teacher's video?  I'm using Python 3.3.  He using a different version perhaps?

Comment: @stevengfowler: If you were using Python 3, `input()` would work. Since it doesn't, this means that you're (inadvertently?) using Python 2.

Comment: When I type python --version, I get Python 3.3.0, though.  So, I must be using 3.3?

Comment: @stevengfowler: I don't have a crystal ball, but the exception in your question could only have come from Python 2.x.

Comment: @stevengfowler: you may be confused about which python is being called.  Add `import sys` and then `print(sys.version)` to the start of your program-- that'll almost certainly show 2.something.

Answer (score 0):

use `raw_input()` for python2 and `input()` in python3.  in python2, `input()` is the same as saying `eval(raw_input())`

if you're running this on the command line, try `$python3 file.py` instead of `$python file.py`  additionally in this `for i in range(len(strong)):` I believe `strong` should say `string`

but this code can be simplified quite a bit

```
def num_vowels(string):
    s = s.lower()
    count = 0
    for c in s: # for each character in the string (rather than indexing)
        if c in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
            # if the character is in the set of vowels (rather than a bunch
            # of 'or's)
            count += 1
    return count

strng = input("Enter a statement:")
print("The number of vowels is:", num_vowels(strng), ".")
```

replacing the '+' with ',' means you don't have to explicitly cast the return of the function to a string

if you'd prefer to use python2, change the bottom part to:

```
strng = raw_input("Enter a statement: ")
print "The number of vowels is:", num_vowels(strng), "."
```